# I'm writing a function which will return a set of unique elements in a nested list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

This is what I have done as of right now,

```
def unique(L):
    '''
    Returns set of unique elements in nested list L
    Ex.      unique([ 2, 1, 4, [ 3, [3, 4], 2 ], [2, 5, 6], 4, [ 2, 1 ]])
    returns: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    '''
    
    result = set()
    for item in L:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            unique(item)
        else:
            result.add(item)
    return result
```

but when I
`print(unique([ 2, 1, 4, [ 3, [3, 4], 2 ], [2, 5, 6], 4, [ 2, 1 ]]))`

the result is {1, 2, 4}.
I'm trying to figure out why the recursion is not picking up the 5 and the 6 in that nested list?
I'm just trying to grasp the recursion concept and it's difficult at first. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively `set.union` when you encounter sublists

```
def unique(L):
    result = set()
    for item in L:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result |= unique(item) # recurse, then union with current set
        else:
            result.add(item)
    return result

>>> unique([ 2, 1, 4, [ 3, [3, 4], 2 ], [2, 5, 6], 4, [ 2, 1 ]])
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

In your current implementation you call `unique(item)` but then do not use the result of that recursive call, so the `result` that gets returned is discarded and not accumulated with the current set of items.

Comment: One might mention that the main issue is that the OP does not process the output of the recursive calls at all.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Good point, let me edit my answer to elaborate that

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to use the recursive call to update `result`.

```
...
if isinstance(item, list):
    result.update(unique(item))
...
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Comment: @azro How do you know that?

Comment: haha yes, this is correct, this is the first recursive function i wrote. Trying to understand the principles.
Thank you both for the input!

Comment: Regarding the questions below my post

Comment: @azro Sorry, why are you telling me? Do you want me to edit and explain it?

Comment: Just telling that "he forgot" is wrong, I don't care what you do with that information

Comment: @azro OK, it doesn't really make a difference to me. If OP wants me to explain it, they can just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the result of `unique(item)`, each `result` is local to it's method call. You need the union of the current and what is returned by the call

```
def unique(L):
    result = set()
    for item in L:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result = result.union(unique(item)) # with method
            # result |= unique(item)            # with operator
        else:
            result.add(item)
    return result

print(unique([2, 1, 4, [3, [3, 4], 2], [2, 5, 6], 4, [2, 1]]))  # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Comment: oh so for each nested list i need to update the result set by using the .union method?

Comment: @Apparent you call `unique` on a new value, you need to use the result of that call in the parent yes

Comment: Why rebind `result` instead of just updating it?

Comment: I see, so there are two ways here to get to the same outcome of result containing all values. @azro

Answer (score 0):

A rather elegant way to do this is separating the flattening from the set-making.

```py
def flatten(nested_list):
    if isinstance(nested_list, list):
        for x in nested_list:
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
    else:
        yield nested_list

def unique(nested_list):
    return set(flatten(nested_list))
```

This isn't the most efficient way to flatten the nested list. If we have a list of `n` elements nested `n` layers deep, it will take `O(n^2)` time to flatten it. For faster flattening, we must be cleverer.

```py
class FlattenIterator:
    def __init__(self, nested_list):
        self.stack = [iter((nested_list,))]
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        while self.stack:
            top_most = self.stack[-1]
            try:
                next_item = next(top_most)
                if isinstance(next_item, list):
                    self.stack.append(iter(next_item))
                else:
                    return next_item
            except StopIteration:
                self.stack.pop()
        raise StopIteration

def unique(nested_list):
    return set(FlattenIterator(nested_list))
```

This solution will be linear in the total amount of space, assuming that the reference graph forms a tree.